# Why is AngularJS rewriting hashbang

Tags: angularjs

Why is AngularJS rewriting the address bar when I enter

```
www.domain.com/index.html/#!/content/sub/content
```

to

```
www.domain.com/index.html#/!/content/sub/content
```

/#/! isn't standard hashbang syntax.. I want to keep it as #!/content/subcontent then parse the url with a custom function.

I've tried

```
$location.html5Mode = false;
```

and

```
angular.module('locationModule', [])

    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        //$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $locationProvider.html5Mode = false;
    });
```

Neither of which seem to make a difference.

Comment: You haven't defined `!` as hashprefix. Default routing doesn't use `!` unless you tell it to

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 mode is disabled by default. This prefix is set by the user if you do not want /#/.

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');`

Comment: Thanks. I also needed to include angular-route.js

Answer (score 0):

$locationProvider, which is part of Angular's core, configures an application's paths. By default, Angular prefixes routes with #!, known as Hashbang mode. This is a convention for showing that a page load is triggered by JavaScript.

I added the following code to my config function in app/scripts/app.js file

Add the following code to the config function:

```
    (function() {
      function config($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider
            .html5Mode({
              enabled: true,
              requireBase: false
            });
      }
```

By setting the html5Mode method's enabled property to true, the hashbang URLs are disabled; that is, users will see clean URLs without the hashbang. Setting the requireBase property to false is unrelated to the hashbang issue, but is one way to avoid a common $location error.